# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede-social\index.php on line 15

Tags: php

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    if(isset($_POST['publish'])) {
       if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
           $texto = $_POST["texto"];
           $hoje = date("Y-m-d");

           if ($texto == "") {
               echo "<h3>Escreva algo antes de publicar!</h3>";
           }else{
               $query = "INSERT INTO pubs (user,texto,data) VALUES ('$login_cookie','$texto','$hoje')";
               $data = mysql_query($query) or die ();
               if ($data)
                   header("Location: ./")
               }else{
                   echo "Algo não correu muito bem...Tente outra vez mais tarde";
               }
            }
          }else{
              $n = rand(0, 1000000);
              $img = $n.$_FILES["file"]["name"];

              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" $img);

              $texto = $_POST['texto'];
              $hoje = date("Y-m-d");

              if ($texto == "") {
                  echo "<h3">Escreva algo antes de publicar!</h3>;
              }else{
                  $query = "INSERT INTO pubs (user,texto,imagem,data) VALUES ('$login_cookie','$texto','$img','$hoje')";
                  $data = mysql_query($query) or die ();
                  if ($data)
                      header("Location: ./")
                  }else{
                      echo "Algo não correu muito bem...Tente outra vez mais tarde";
                  }
               }
             }
        }
?>
<html>
<header>
    <style type="text/css">
    div#publish{width: 400px; height: 210px; display: block; margin: auto; border: none; border-radius: 5px; background: #FFF; box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000; margin-top: 30px;}
    div#publish textarea{width: 365; height: 100px; display: block; margin: auto; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px; border-width: 1px; border-color: #A1A1A1;}
    div#publish img{margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 10px; width: 40px; cursor: pointer;}
    div#publish input[type="submit"]{width: 70px; height: 25px; border-radius: 3px; float: right; margin-right: 15px; border: none; margin-top: 5px; background: #000; color: #FFF; cursor: pointer;}
    div#publish input[type="submit"]:hover{background: #001F3F;}
    </style>
</header>
<body>
    <div id="publish">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <br />
             <textarea placeholder="Escreve uma publicação nova" name="texto"></textarea>
             <label for="file-input">
                 <img src="img/camera-icon.png" title="Inserir uma foto" />
                 </label>
                 <input type="submit" value="Publicar" name="publish" />

                 <input type="file" id="file-input" name="file" hidden />
          </form>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema é que você não fechou todos os `if` adequadamente, fechando até mais do que deveria, e esquecendo de abrir alguns. A solução é bem básica, só olhar as aberturas e os fechamentos:

```
<?php
include ("header.php");

if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        $texto = $_POST["texto"];
        $hoje = date("Y-m-d");
        if ($texto == "") {
            echo "<h3>Escreva algo antes de publicar!</h3>";
        }
        else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO pubs (user,texto,data) VALUES ('$login_cookie','$texto','$hoje')";
            $data = mysql_query($query) or die();
            if ($data) {
                header("Location: ./");
            }
            else {
                echo "Algo não correu muito bem...Tente outra vez mais tarde";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $n = rand(0, 1000000);
        $img = $n . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/"$img);
        $texto = $_POST['texto'];
        $hoje = date("Y-m-d");
        if ($texto == "") {
            echo "<h3>Escreva algo antes de publicar!</h3>";
        }
        else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO pubs (user,texto,imagem,data) VALUES ('$login_cookie','$texto','$img','$hoje')";
            $data = mysql_query($query) or die();
            if ($data){
                header("Location: ./");
            }
            else {
                echo "Algo não correu muito bem...Tente outra vez mais tarde";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ainda continua o erro Francisco

Comment: Certeza? Testei aqui e ta funcionando.

Comment: tenho sim, mas ja arrumei o erro, so que agr ta dando erro abaixo da linha do </html>